# Accessing HTML that loads in AJAX

Tags: ajax, casperjs

I'm trying to use CasperJS on an application that loads only the skeleton of the page when accessing the page. Then it loads the main content in AJAX.

Basically, my code appears after loading in the following div

```
    <div class="content"></div>
```

It seems that CasperJS can't access the content of this div after the initial load. And it's too bad because the entire app is within this tag (don't blame me, blame the devs who used Backbone).

After an extensive search, I found that I could perhaps use the `evaluate` function to do a `document.body.innerHTML` to dump the content of the requested HTML in the document, but it does not seem to work.

Any idea? Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get the div contents by using evaluate, as you found out. The eval'd function should return the desired value.

If the content is loaded via AJAX, you should also wait until it's loaded. I'd suggest using this:

```
var body_html;
this.waitForSelectorTextChange('div.content', function() {
   body_html = this.evaluate(function() {
       return document.body.innerHTML;
   });
});
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks so much @gontrollez. I can't test it right now to see if this works but I'll check and let you know if it worked.